# Search with queries constrained to elements using search:search

Tags: search, marklogic, marklogic-9

What i want to do is similar in the following link but we want it using `search:search`:

- [Queries Constrained to Elements](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/245/0/queries-constrained-to-elements)

Basically we have 2 xmls like the following:

#### XML-1

```xml
<rootElement>
   <id>7635940284725382300</id>
   <parentElement>
      <childElement1>ce1-A</childElement1>
      <childElement2>ce2-1</childElement2>
   </parentElement>
   <parentElement>
      <childElement1>ce1-B</childElement1>
      <childElement2>ce2-2</childElement2>
      </parentElement>
   <parentElement>
      <childElement1>ce1-C</childElement1>
      <childElement2>ce2-3</childElement2>
   </parentElement>
</rootElement>
```

#### XML-2

```xml
<rootElement>
   <id>7635940284725382398</id>
   <parentElement>
      <childElement1>ce1-A</childElement1>
      <childElement2>ce2-2</childElement2>
   </parentElement>
   <parentElement>
      <childElement1>ce1-B</childElement1>
      <childElement2>ce2-3</childElement2>
      </parentElement>
   <parentElement>
      <childElement1>ce1-C</childElement1>
      <childElement2>ce2-4</childElement2>
   </parentElement>
</rootElement>
```

So now what i want to do is to have a match for `childElement1` and `childElement2` within the same `parentElement`.

For example:

If i search with values `childElement1 = ce1-B` and `childElement2 = ce2-3`, it should only give me `XML-2` and not return `XML-1`.

We have achieved this using the `cts:search` query as explained in the link:

```
cts:search (/, 
     cts:element-query (
         xs:QName ('parentElement'),
         cts:and-query ((
             cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('childElement1'), 'ce1-B', 'exact'),
             cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('childElement2'), 'ce2-3', 'exact')
         ))
     )
)
```

#### Question:

We are using `search:search` with different `search:constraint`s? I have read about using [`container`](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_52102) for this but there are no good examples to show how it can be used.

Here is our sample `search:search`, so need to tweak this to have the same functionality as that shown by `cts:search` query shown above:

```xml
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:search("childElement1:ce1-B AND childElement2:ce2-3 sort:childElement2ASC"
    , <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
        <term>
            <term-option xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">unstemmed</term-option>
            <empty apply="all-results" />
            <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
            <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
        </term>

        <transform-results apply="transformed-result" ns="http://isearchgui/search" at="/customResultSet.xqy" />

        <search:constraint name="childElement1">
            <search:range type="xs:string" facet="false" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en">
                <search:path-index ns="http://my.search.com/something">//childElement1</search:path-index>
            </search:range>
        </search:constraint>

        <search:constraint name="childElement2">
            <search:range type="xs:string" facet="false" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en">
                <search:path-index ns="http://my.search.com/something">//childElement2</search:path-index>
            </search:range>
        </search:constraint>

        <search:operator name="sort">
            <search:state name="childElement1ASC">
                <search:sort-order direction="ascending" type="xs:string">
                <search:path-index ns="http://my.search.com/something">//childElement1</search:path-index>
                </search:sort-order>
            </search:state>
            <search:state name="childElement1DES">
                <search:sort-order direction="descending" type="xs:string">
                <search:path-index ns="http://my.search.com/something">//childElement1</search:path-index>
                </search:sort-order>
            </search:state>
            <search:state name="childElement2ASC">
                <search:sort-order direction="ascending" type="xs:string">
                <search:path-index ns="http://my.search.com/something">//childElement2</search:path-index>
                </search:sort-order>
            </search:state>
            <search:state name="childElement2DES">
                <search:sort-order direction="descending" type="xs:string">
                <search:path-index ns="http://my.search.com/something">//childElement2</search:path-index>
                </search:sort-order>
            </search:state>
        </search:operator>
    </options>
    , 0
    , 15);
```

Hope this helps to answer.

Comment: How do you expect `search:search` to work? Do you want to build a constraint for those elements? For the container? Update your question to make it clear exactly what behavior you want.

Comment: @wst Hope the edit helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Use the `container` option, which works like any other constraint option, then wrap your nested query in parenthesis.

For example:

```
search:parse('contain:(test one two)',
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <constraint name="contain">
      <container>
        <element ns="" name="parentElement"/>
      </container>
    </constraint>    
  </options>)
```

=>

```
  <cts:element-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
    <cts:element>parentElement</cts:element>
    <cts:and-query>
      <cts:word-query>
        <cts:text xml:lang="en">test</cts:text>
      </cts:word-query>
      <cts:word-query>
        <cts:text xml:lang="en">one</cts:text>
      </cts:word-query>
      <cts:word-query>
        <cts:text xml:lang="en">two</cts:text>
      </cts:word-query>
    </cts:and-query>
  </cts:element-query>
```

So in your case you would have the main-search string as :

```
search:search('contain:(childElement1:ce1-B AND childElement2:ce2-3) sort:childElement2ASC', <options ....)
```

Comment: Doesn't give the desired results. It checks everywhere within the parent element not considering only certain child elements with the value.

Comment: @PrakashK You have to nest your current query within the container query. The word queries in my answer were only used as an example of how nesting works in the Search API grammar. Yours would be like `contain:(childElement1:ce1-B AND childElement2:ce2-3) sort:childElement2ASC`.

Comment: You may want to enable positions on the indexes that you use to allow running with accurate numbers in unfiltered mode..

Comment: Ok! Thanks will try and let you know.